# Is it better to bet on a d12 or on the sum of two d6?

Tags: probability, dice

The game is simple we throw a $d12$ and two $d6s$. We sum the value of the outcomes of the two $d6$ and compare it with the outcome of the $d12$.

If the sum of the two $d6$ is higher, $d6$ wins, if the $d12$ has a higher value, $d12$ wins. I have run a simulation and it is pretty clear that one should bet on the $d6s$. However, I it is also pretty clear that this should not be because of their higher expected value. (Expected value $d6s = 7$ and expected value $d12 = 6,5$). In fact, one can easily concoct scenarios with different dices in which even the expected value of a dice is higher, but the probability of winning is lower.

Am I right to think that the correct way to calculate the probability of winning this game is to compare every possible outcome of the two $d6$; i.e., $36$ outcomes, with every possible outcome of the $d12$; i.e., $12$ outcomes, and simply count those in which $d6 > d12$ over the total?

In this case there are $36 \times 12$ total possible outcomes of $d12$ and two $d6$s throws. In these, $180$ are won by the $d12$. Thus, the probability of winning with the $d12$ is $5/12$. Is this correct?

Comment: I think so (if I understand the problem). It appears that the probability of a tie is $1/12$ and the probability of the $2\text{d}6$ winning outright is $1/2$. ¶ The $1/12$ is easy by virtue of independence: The $\text{d}12$ ties the $2\text{d}6$ no matter what the latter roll up. There might be a cleverer way of computing the win probabilities, but a minute of thinking about it didn't conjure it up for me.

Comment: Oh never mind, there is a reasonably quick way of deducing the $1/2$ (which leads immediately to the $5/12$). I'll write it up when I have a moment.

Comment: Formally, your **generic** approach of comparing each possible 2d6 roll with each possible d12 roll is good.  I suspect that the shortcut that Brian Tung is referring to, attempts to capitalize on ideas around the symmetry of the 2d6 and d12 distributions.  Personally, I am unsure whether a symmetric-analysis shortcut is possible because of the difference in expected values between (6.5) and (7).  If it were me, I would attempt to attack the problem **both ways**, and see where this leads.  Such an attack would then give insights to the *generic* problem of 2dm :: dn.

Comment: @user2661923: Yes, it's symmetry-based. But more than that, I *think* it relies on the fact that the range of the $2\text{d}6$ starts one above the $\text{d}12$ and stops at the same point. It doesn't generalize very well at all. There may be some other clever method that does generalize, but this isn't it, I don't believe.

Comment: @BrianTung Contrast this problem with 2d8::d20, where you first identify the probability of d20 $~=~ \geq 17~$ or d20 $~=~ 1.$  Then, you would be left with d20 (*more or less*) matching with 2d8.  This is what I am thinking.  It wouldn't be that different from your 2d6::d12 symmetry analysis.

Comment: @user2661923: You might be right at that. I haven't had much time to think about it, I'm afraid! ETA: It just occurred to me that although the multiplication might be slightly more annoying, it's probably pretty straightforward still as long as one of the sides is a single die. I'll generalize as much as I can when I write it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have two discrete random variables:

- $X$ is *uniformly* distributed over the set $1, 2, \ldots, 12$
- $Y$ is *symmetrically* distributed over the set $2, 3, \ldots, 12$

Because of the symmetry of $Y$'s distribution, we have

- $P(Y > 1) = 1-P(Y > 12)$
- $P(Y > 2) = 1-P(Y > 11)$
- $\cdots$
- $P(Y > 6) = 1-P(Y > 7)$

or in general, $P(Y > k) = 1-P(Y > 13-k)$. Then by the law of total probability,

\begin{align}
P(Y > X)
    & = \sum_{k = 1}^{12} P(Y > X \mid X = k) P(X = k) \\
    & = \sum_{k = 1}^{12} P(Y > k) P(X = k) \\
    & = \sum_{k = 1}^6 [P(Y > k) + P(Y > 13-k)] P(X = k) \\
    & = \sum_{k = 1}^6 P(X = k) \\
    & = \sum_{k = 1}^6 \frac{1}{12} \\
    & = \frac12
\end{align}

We also observe that

\begin{align}
P(Y = X)
    & = \sum_{k = 2}^{12} P(X = Y \mid Y = k) P(Y = k) \\
    & = \sum_{k = 2}^{12} P(X = k) P(Y = k) \\
    & = \sum_{k = 2}^{12} \frac{1}{12} P(Y = k) \\
    & = \frac{1}{12} \sum_{k = 2}^{12} P(Y = k) \\
    & = \frac{1}{12}
\end{align}

Therefore, $P(Y < X) = 1 - P(Y > X) - P(Y = X) = 5/12$. So yes:

> tl;dr: You were right.

And also: You can just count the cases as (I think) you did.

---

There are various ways to generalize this, provided the symmetry of $Y$'s distribution is symmetrically covered by $X$'s distribution. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader, or perhaps I'll come back and sketch it out, right around the time hell freezes over.

Comment: The way I looked at it, the $\mathrm d12$ rolls $1$ (which is always a loss) with probability $1/12.$ With probability $11/12,$ the $\mathrm d12$ is uniformly distributed from $2$ to $12.$ The uniform $2$ to $12$ and the $2\mathrm d6$ are symmetric around the same mean, so each wins equally often; but the original $\mathrm d12$ has already lost $1/12$ of the games, so it loses more often than it wins. We might be able to get the $1/2$ and $5/12$ out of that too, but I stopped thinking about it once I knew the $2\mathrm d6$ had the advantage.

Comment: Shouldn't this be generalizable to all $X$ being discrete and uniform over $(1,...,2n)$ and all $Y$ being symmetric over $(2,...,2n)$? I mean that the probability of a tie will always be $1/2n$ and the probability of win over that total of games $50%$?